# My wifi connection automatically turns off when I close the lid of my laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, connection, internet-connection, standby

My wifi connection automatically turns off or lose some connection when I close the lid of my laptop.
When my laptop lose some connection and is still connected doesen't work.

Thank's

Comment: How old is the laptop? As far as I know, most laptops have the wifi antenna in the screen part of the laptop. It might be that there is a loose connection which is being severed or disrupted when you close the lid

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior on Windows 10 is for a laptop to enter sleep mode when its lid is closed:

[image]

Try changing this setting from "Sleep" to "Do Nothing" and see if it solves your problem:

[image]

You can access these settings by simply searching for "lid" from the Start menu:

[image]